# Using Google Places API to display on leaflet/ Alternatives

Tags: javascript, google-maps, leaflet, google-places-api, gis

I am building a map with leaflet that displays community services nearby schools. I have used the google places api to find the schools and put them on the map. It has come to my attention that this is against the google terms of service:

> If your application displays Google Places API Web Service data on a map, that map must be provided by Google.

At this stage in the project it is not realistic to change to google maps api as there are already many other dependencies, is there an alternative source I could use to find nearby community services which will allow me to display them on a leaflet map?

Comment: Since you're using Leaflet: have you considered [Leaflet.GoogleMutant](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant) ?